# Tikz - How to add an icon on top of a connecting line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to add a WiFi icon on top of a connecting line. What do I have to add here?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{app} = [draw=yellow!25,fill=yellow!25,circle,node distance=1cm,font=\sffamily,thick]
\tikzstyle{device} = [draw=blue!40,fill=blue!15,rectangle,node distance=1cm,font=\sffamily,thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,font=\sffamily]
\node [app,align=center] (N1) {Node 1};
\node [device,align=center,right=60mm of N1] (N2) {Node 2};
\draw (N1) -- (N2) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {Place WiFi icon here};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example pdf]

Comment: `\includegraphics{...}` as content of `(TextNode)`?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{fontawesome}` and use `\faWifi` in your `TextNode`.

Comment: @AlexG This works for me!

Comment: Perhaps, using a special font glyph, as suggested by @PaulG, is even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an implementation of the comment by Paul Gaborit

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % added the cool package
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{app} = [draw=yellow!25,fill=yellow!25,circle,node distance=1cm,font=\sffamily,thick]
\tikzstyle{device} = [draw=blue!40,fill=blue!15,rectangle,node distance=1cm,font=\sffamily,thick]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,font=\sffamily]
        \node [app,align=center] (N1) {Node 1};
        \node [device,align=center,right=60mm of N1] (N2) {Node 2};
        \draw (N1) -- (N2) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {\faWifi};%the \faWifi is new here 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

returns:

[image]

Comment: @PaulGaborit thanks ;-) You did all the work though. (I started drawing a wifi symbol in LaTeX, since I couldn't figure out if one already existed)

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, a `TikZ` wifi icon (at least something similar).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    app/.style={
        draw=yellow!25, fill=yellow!25, circle,
        node distance=1cm, font=\sffamily, thick
    },
    device/.style={
        draw=blue!40, fill=blue!15, rectangle,
        node distance=1cm, font=\sffamily, thick
    },
    wifi/.pic={
        \fill[black]circle (1pt);
        \draw[line width=1.5pt,
        decorate,
        decoration={
            expanding waves,
            angle=45,
            segment length=3pt}] (0,0)--++(90:4mm);
    }]

    \node [app,align=center] (N1) {Node 1};
    \node [device,align=center,right=60mm of N1] (N2) {Node 2};
    \draw (N1) -- pic[yshift=1mm]{wifi} (N2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

off-topic modification of [Thorbjørn E. K. Christensen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/125223/thorbj%C3%B8rn-e-k-christensen) answer:

- shorter code,
- not used obsolete syntax for defining of image elements style (used by op)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % added the cool package

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 60mm,
  base/.style = {font=\sffamily, thick},
   app/.style = {base,circle, draw=yellow!50,fill=yellow!25},
device/.style = {base,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!25}
                        ]
\node [app] (N1) {Node 1};
\node [device,right=of N1] (N2) {Node 2};
\draw (N1) -- node [above,font=\Large] {\faWifi} (N2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]